# Joomla, добавляться в коде везде pagespeed

Tags: php, joomla

Привет,

Проблема на сайте на **Joomla**. В коде везде добавляется **pagespeed** + атрибуты типа `data-pagespeed-` . В коде пишет, что это `<script>eval(mod_pagespeed_EPhnDpeLOD);</script>` (таких много скриптов), но я не могу найти данного разширения или модуля в админке. Может как то по другому называтся?

Очень буду благодарен за помощь.
Version Joomla! 2.5.27 Stable.

Скрины аттачу: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В моем случае решение такое:

В файл `.htaccess` добавил такой код:

```
<IfModule mod_pagespeed>
  ModPagespeed off
</IfModule>
```

И в админке хостера почистил кеш.